# Lost safari remote debugging after update to ios8.3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, remote-debugging

Has anyone encountered this issue. I lost the ability to use safari remote debugging after updating ios, xcode and safari. Safari on the desktop does see the phone and it is listed in the developer menu but my ionic app is no longer accessible. I have rebooted the phone. I have tried to remote debug from two separate development machines both are unable to see the ionic app.

Additionally, xcode also fails to connect when you try attach. At first it looks like it is working but then it fails.

Any help would be appreciated. I am stuck.

Comment: Did you try GapDebug instead?

Comment: GapDebug has similar issue.  When trying to install app it eventually disconnects.

Comment: what version of Safari are you on?

Comment: 8.0.5.  Keep in mind that this was working before updating to ios8.3 and xcode 6.3.2

Comment: I had this problem when I updated xcode and the solution was to close safari completely and open it again

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I need to download a new provisioning profile and refresh the profile in xcode.  once this was done it was back to working.